# Remove lines if the second field is blank

Tags: text-processing, awk

here is my file,the delimiter between the two fields (\t).

```
1   a
2   b
3   
4   d
5
6   e
```

i want to get the intermediate file

```
1  a
2  b
4  d
6  e
```

and the final file

```
>1
a
>2
b
>4
d
>6
e
```

Comment: Do you REALLY need the intermediate file or do you just THINK that's something you'll need to create on your way to the final file?

Comment: What's the delimiter between the first two fields (tab?). Is the second field always a single character, or may it be longer? If longer than a single character, may it contain tabs or spaces? Is the second field allowed to _start with_ a space or tab?

Comment: I notice that you have asked several questions by now but haven't accepted _any_ of the answers that you have received. Consider accepting the most helpful answers to each question. Doing so will mark the issue as resolved, and it will also increase your chances of getting help in the future. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Do you really have only two characters in each field or can there be more? Can you have lines like `123  asdaajdokjfdslkfjsdpoiurqewkmlnafjhdsf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `file` contains:

```
$ cat file
1   a
2   b
3   
4   d
5
6   e
```

And assuming that either several spaces or/and tabs work as delimiters, try this:

```
$ awk '$2!=""' file
1   a
2   b
4   d
6   e
```

For the intermediate file and this:

```
$ awk '$2!=""{printf ">%s\n%s%s",$1,$2,ORS}' file
>1
a
>2
b
>4
d
>6
e
```

To get the final file.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question `awk`, but some lonely `sed -i` is fooling around, so I dare to give an `sed` solution:

```
sed -En 's/^([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)$/>\1\
\2/p' yourfile
```

This is separating the "filled" lines into three parts:

- The number at the start `^[0-9]+`
- The whitespaces or tabs `[[:space:]]+`
- the alphanumeric second column `[[:alnum:]]+`

The first and third part are surrounded by `()`, so they can be reused as `\1` and `\2` in the replacement.

The newline in the replacement needs to be preceeded by a backslash.

The `p`rint flag to the `s`ubstitute command outputs the buffer only if a replacement was possible, while other output is suppressed by the `-n` option. This way only lines with a second entry are processed.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne '.put if .words[1];'
```

Sample Input:

```
1   a
2   b
3   
4   d
5
6   e
```

Sample Output (1):

```
1   a
2   b
4   d
6   e
```

To convert Sample Output (1) to Sample Output (2):

```perl
raku -ne '.map(">" ~ *).words.join("\n").put;' 

#OR

raku -ne '.put for .map(">" ~ *).words;'
```

Sample Output (2):

```
>1
a
>2
b
>4
d
>6
e
```

All together [ produces Sample Output (2) from Sample Input ]:

```perl
raku -ne '.map(">" ~ *).words.join("\n").put if .words[1] ;' 

#OR

raku -ne 'if .words[1] {.put for .map(">" ~ *).words};'
```

https://raku.org